# openstreetmap : is this way in a city or in the countryside?

Tags: geolocation, openstreetmap

I'm using openStreetMap data using lat/lon position  to find if either :

- a road (way) is inside a town/city/village
- a road (way) is in the countryside

Actually i can retrieve the road and all the corresponding nodes but i can't find how to link it to the place information.

I have already try to use the place tag , but the road (way) and nodes retrieved have no place tag.

any ideas ?

Comment: You could perform a reverse-geocoding query, see if it returns a city and then calculate the distance of this city to your current point. If it doesn't return a city then you aren't within the distance of any.

Comment: using nominatim reverse-geocoding always returns village or city when i test it ( there's a lot of village in France).

Comment: Then evaluate the distance of this city to your point and determine for yourself whether the way is near the city or not. Alternatively try to obtain the administrative boundary relation of this city and check whether it contains the way or not. This relation might not be available for every city in OSM.